Glyph origin and etymology of 羹?
Cantonese likely uses 羹 more often than Mandarin being associated with the term for "spoon" 匙羹, which is obviously used for soups and broths. But what's the story behind this character 羹? How did a "lamb" that is "pretty" end up becoming the meaning of "broth" and "stew"?

Here's Outlier's breakdown:

FORM
羹 is composed of 美 and 羔 “a sheep being barbequed,” which indicate the  original meaning “vegetable or mutton soup cooked in a bronze vessel, like a dǐng (鼎) or lì (鬲).”
COMPONENTS
羔
In 羹, 羔 “mutton; sheep meat” is a  meaning component, pointing to the  original meaning “vegetable or mutton soup cooked in a bronze vessel, like a dǐng (鼎) or lì (鬲).”
美
In 羹, 美 is an  empty component. It was originally 鬲 lì “cooking cauldron” and 灬 “fire”.
MEANINGS
gēng
1 (orig.) vegetable or mutton soup cooked in a bronze vessel, like a dǐng (鼎) or lì (鬲)
2 → thick soup

It doesn't mention the meaning of spoon here but I think the semantic extensions are pretty logical. For instance, in some dialects the expression 调羹儿 or 调羹 exists for spoon, which literally means "[the] [item] [which] stirs(?) (mixes(?)) [the] soup." Extensions from there are even more far reaching, Southwestern Mandairn has "瓢羹儿" (piao ger) for example which is probably just a corruption on the initial /t‘/ ---> /p‘/.
In Cantonese 匙羹 looks more like "soup spoon," but again, due to the fluidity of Chinese 羹 has also come to carry the abbreviated meaning of spoon. This is not unsimilar to other southern topolects, like mentioned above.
